# XCode crashes at start (at launch)

Tags: macos, xcode, crash

My XCode crashes with the following error

```
Process:               Xcode [972]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.2.1 (15526.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-15526001000000000~4 (11B500)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [972]
User ID:               167860746

Date/Time:             2020-07-20 16:14:09.203 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0B196765-5F42-FDBE-EF0C-E0879215BB57

Sleep/Wake UUID:       EF4EEF31-7B40-43FF-B0D2-316C16B8E1AE

Time Awake Since Boot: 970 seconds
Time Since Wake:       270 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        28  Dispatch queue: Diff queue for DVTDiffContext <0x7fe80b26e9a0>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000700003400000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [972]

VM Regions Near 0x700003400000:
    Stack                  000070000337e000-0000700003400000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 28
--> STACK GUARD            0000700003400000-0000700003401000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 25
    Stack                  0000700003401000-0000700003483000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 25

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11B500

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2c26eabd RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2c26e7d5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 584
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2c26e579 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a8b6829 _DPSNextEvent + 883
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a8b5070 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000102f8dfeb -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a8a6d7e -[NSApplication run] + 658
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a878b86 NSApplicationMain + 777
13  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000102667e8d main + 541
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6763ccc9 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: <IDEXCBuildSupport.IDEXCBuildServiceBuildOperation:0x7fe80b473cd0:REfc>-builder-queue (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777de36 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3aed _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3fbf _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 98
3   libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00007fff670ab17f OS_dispatch_semaphore.wait(wallTimeout:) + 15
4   com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000012900b8a2 closure #1 in IDEXCBuildServiceBuildOperation.addOperations(to:) + 306
5   com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x0000000129002829 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 25
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9ac5 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb99e6 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 80
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675ef2b9 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: -[IDEExecutionEnvironment initWithWorkspaceArena:] (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff67780882 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841425 _pthread_cond_wait + 698
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcc8ecb -[NSOperation waitUntilFinished] + 697
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fe5b270 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_WAITING_ON_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fd87df0 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 229
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010352738f __61-[IDEScheme _groupAndImposeDependenciesForOrderedOperations:]_block_invoke + 10
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280bf2d __DVTOPERATIONGROUP_CREATED_BY_CALLEE_IS_WAITING_ON_SUBOPERATIONS__ + 164
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c196 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 69
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c146 -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 113
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675ef2b9 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fe80b4709b0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff67780882 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841425 _pthread_cond_wait + 698
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcc8ecb -[NSOperation waitUntilFinished] + 697
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fe5b270 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_WAITING_ON_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fd87df0 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 229
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001035a0c2f __75-[IDEBuildOperationGroup initWithBuildOperations:otherOperations:buildLog:]_block_invoke + 10
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280bf2d __DVTOPERATIONGROUP_CREATED_BY_CALLEE_IS_WAITING_ON_SUBOPERATIONS__ + 164
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c196 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 69
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c146 -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 113
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675ef2b9 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd81c8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011acd844e +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 204
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd07a2 __NSThread__start__ + 1064
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd81c8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011ace5f7d -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 636
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd07a2 __NSThread__start__ + 1064
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff677860fe __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d66ace3 __CFSocketManager + 641
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 12:: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff67780882 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841425 _pthread_cond_wait + 698
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff64910592 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff31e3c224 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 84
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff31e40a2b bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 299
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff31e405f9 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff31e42cd7 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 39
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 13:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2aa58144 _NSEventThread + 132
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 14:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fe80b46bfb0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff67780882 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841425 _pthread_cond_wait + 698
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcc8ecb -[NSOperation waitUntilFinished] + 697
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fe5b270 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_WAITING_ON_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fd87df0 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 229
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001035a0c3b __75-[IDEBuildOperationGroup initWithBuildOperations:otherOperations:buildLog:]_block_invoke_2 + 10
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280bf2d __DVTOPERATIONGROUP_CREATED_BY_CALLEE_IS_WAITING_ON_SUBOPERATIONS__ + 164
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c196 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 69
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010280c146 -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 113
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675ef2b9 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd81c8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fd8ac6f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x00000001205245a9 -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 126
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd07a2 __NSThread__start__ + 1064
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777ddfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d641f85 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d640a52 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d63fece CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d6c8519 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x000000012479e146 closure #1 in FSEventStream.start() + 262
7   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x000000012461c7a2 closure #1 in Thread.init(task:) + 146
8   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x000000012461c8f9 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 25
9   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x000000012461c8be @objc ThreadImpl.main() + 46
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcd07a2 __NSThread__start__ + 1064
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67841109 _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19:: Dispatch queue: Working Copy Cached Location Queue (QOS: UTILITY)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777de36 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3aed _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3fbf _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 98
3   com.apple.dt.Xcode.DVTSourceControl 0x000000010f04d5d3 __52-[DVTSourceControlWorkingCopy updateCachedLocations]_block_invoke + 141
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9ac5 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb99e6 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 80
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675ef2b9 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 25:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control File Path Processesing Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777e672 __getattrlist + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fc7caa7 _NSResolveSymlinksInPathUsingCache + 1009
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fc7c56b -[NSString(NSPathUtilities) _stringByResolvingSymlinksInPathUsingCache:] + 155
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001035b7f30 __64-[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor addWorkspaceFilePathToCheck:]_block_invoke + 280
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001029803ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000102981a92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e26c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e8c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e95d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783da3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 26:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control Fetch File Reference Status Processing Queue (QOS: BACKGROUND)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6777de4e semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3b6b _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 76
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3f97 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010328dd79 __91-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree _updateStatus:forceAuthentication:workspace:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 807
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000102952375 -[DVTOperation main] + 287
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e26c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e5818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783d9f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 28 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: Diff queue for DVTDiffContext <0x7fe80b26e9a0>
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d5cddcb __CFStrConvertBytesToUnicode + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d5d4633 _CFStringCheckAndGetCharacters + 128
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d5d4594 -[__NSCFString getCharacters:range:] + 30
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001027d05df __FNVHash_block_invoke + 229
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001027d04bb FNVHash + 364
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001027d001b -[DVTDiffContextOperation _buildDiffDescriptors] + 958
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001027cf88e -[DVTDiffContextOperation main] + 734
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb9981 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb8bb3 -[NSOperation start] + 722
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb88d9 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2fcb87a9 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e26c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e8c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675e95d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff675f2c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783da3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 30:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 32:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6783cb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 28 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000000132b0  rbx: 0x00007fe815500000  rcx: 0x0000000000000066  rdx: 0x0000000000117d76
  rdi: 0x00007fe815500018  rsi: 0x00007000033d9aa0  rbp: 0x00007000033d9a70  rsp: 0x00007000033d9a68
   r8: 0x00007fff84fc23a0   r9: 0x0000000000117d76  r10: 0x0000000000117d76  r11: 0x00007fff2d5d4576
  r12: 0x00007fe815500000  r13: 0x0000000000117d76  r14: 0x00007fff7194908d  r15: 0x00007fe80d2859b0
  rip: 0x00007fff2d5cddcb  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000700003400000
  
Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000006 (no mapping for user data write)
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x102666000 -        0x102668fff  com.apple.dt.Xcode (11.2.1 - 15526.1) <615B5CCD-2B93-3F76-826B-8205D032D0E1> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x102671000 -        0x102699fff  com.apple.dt.DVTCocoaAdditionsKit (11.2.1 - 15513) <DBA5A0F1-54DE-3CC0-89EA-4E33075A0253> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit
       0x1026c1000 -        0x102cc0ff7  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (11.2.1 - 15513) <E922EEB1-FDC0-3233-93DF-195446D2DAD4> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x102f78000 -        0x10311ffff  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (11.2.1 - 15513) <A0941A35-13EC-32B0-8A09-4696E758480D> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x10324b000 -        0x103b2ffff  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (11.2.1 - 15526.1) <42FBCB43-0A9E-3012-9270-6D42F08BCD14> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x10422f000 -        0x104be3fff  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (11.2.1 - 15526.1) <D2BA1164-38BD-3373-8A09-17DDB8157E01> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x10537e000 -        0x1053bdff3  com.apple.DebugSymbols (194 - 194) <9B2838A7-E292-3008-B7B0-4A4CCBA423F6> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DebugSymbolsDT.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbolsDT
       0x1053df000 -        0x105465ffb  com.apple.CoreSymbolicationDT (11.2.1 - 64531.4) <340FC7F4-7582-38D1-BB9E-D05B0BE241C3> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolicationDT
       0x1054b9000 -        0x1054b9ff7  com.apple.contentdelivery.ContentDeliveryServices (4.00 - 1181) <1C5E9577-E8B8-30FB-92DE-BB90F77EF40A> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/ContentDeliveryServices
       0x1054c0000 -        0x1054e7ff3  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (11.2.1 - 64531.2) <56DECC43-6C08-3086-86CA-982830D32A5D> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
```

I tried to google and found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451126/xcode-crashes-on-launch
and tried to delete DerivedData folder but this hasn't resolved the problem and it keeps crashing. I don’t have admin credentials on my machine, so I’m severely limited in what I can change.

Do I have to reinstall XCode or is there any other solution or workaround?

Comment: The current version of Xcode is 11.6, you seem to use 11.2.1. So updating Xcode might be a good thing to do anyway.

Comment: hold shift and click Xcode in the Dock to open it.

Comment: How would you reinstall Xcode without admin permissions? Or maybe you’re an admin but somehow can’t add a user account?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new user account on the Mac first. Log out of your current user, and then log in to the new user account.

1. If Xcode crashes in the new account, you will know it’s not any data or user settings and focus on reinstalling the OS / rebooting the OS / reinstalling the app.

If Xcode does not crash on the new account, now you know how much time to spend triaging it. If you can move all your data and settings to the new account in 30 minutes - spend that time researching this and then move accounts.

Now, since this is a managed account you are forced to get help from an administrator or read the exact crash and hope it helps you determine why the app is crashing. In this case, you can watch the stack trace on each thread - especially the one that crashes and watch carefully what you do leading up to the crash.

```
Thread 28 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: Diff queue for DVTDiffContext <0x7fe80b26e9a0>
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d5cddcb __CFStrConvertBytesToUnicode + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2d5d4633 _CFStringCheckAndGetCharacters + 128
```

Xcode is converting bytes to Unicode, so perhaps this is a class name or something being rendered?

Comment: I don't have permissions to create user accounts on the office laptop, so this is not an option for me

Comment: @Patlatus Well - that makes it easy - get IT to help. If that’s not tenable, you will have to remove things until you have nothing on that account. I’ll put in an edit to the answer since you have a materially different situation now that we know your machine is managed and you are not even an administrator on it.